# I accidentally executed the following command, what did I lose and how do I recover it?

Tags: sudo

I was trying to uninstall the C++ Boost libraries and ran the following command: "sudo apt-get autoremove libboost*"

Comment: Do you still have the output of the command? If not, have a look at the log files `/var/log/apt/history.log` and `/var/log/apt/term.log` and please [edit] your question to include everything related to the incident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` is a wildcard which selects all files with the same name/pattern. In my opinion these things will get removed:

- libboost-date-time
- libboost-filesystem
- libboost-iostreams
- libboost-locale
- libboost-system
- libboost-thread

To recover them simply run 
`sudo apt-get install <package name>`

**Note:** I have assumed that there were not many things installed in your system, i.e. it was a clean install.